# Which XP version does Visual Studio 2012 supports [As Target OS]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++11, windows-xp

Which version of windows XP does Visual Studio 2012 supports.
[Edit: Which version does VS12 supports compiling to]

I found this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

That states that it supports XP SP3. But I didn't find any information for VS12 update 4.

Also, If the code I compile using VS12 doesn't crush on XP SP2 and seems to work.
Is it safe to use it? why not?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of XP? None anymore. XP isn't supported.

Comment: Take your lead from Microsoft: XP isn't supported. On a related note: continuing support for ancient software merely encourages users to continue using it. If software vendors pulled the plug on support for such products users would be encouraged to move to more secure systems more quickly.

Comment: @MikeW: Visual C++ 2013 can target Windows XP. That's a wholly different issue from OS support. That said, re the implication that later Windows versions are more secure, that's debatable, and I for one would not agree at all (for good reasons).

Comment: @MikeW Why throw away something that works? Even today there are still systems running that was originally created in the 1960s, granted they have been updated over the years but the core is probably still the same COBOL code that was made originally. Do you throw away your phone every time a new phone comes out? Ancient software (and hardware) is what makes this world go round, it would be madness to try and rewrite it every time something new and (ostensibly) better comes along. Also, just because some companies abandon their biggest customer base doesn't mean you should too.

Comment: Microsoft's use of the word "supports" in their documentation means something else than what you are asking. It literally means that they'll answer the phone and help you solve your problem. XP support is over, companies can still buy it if they are willing to spend the money. You however mean "compatible with". Yes, I'm sure there's no problem on SP2, surely not on the original RTM release either.  Stay out of trouble, it is your user's choice to not update their machines.  State your prerequisites explicitly and don't promise what you have not tested.

Comment: When compiled to XP with the v110_xp toolset - the functions "EncodePointer" and "DecodePointer" are imported from kernel32. These functions are provided only from XP SP2. Is there a way to make it work on XP SP0\SP1?

Answer (score 2):

It's correct, Visual Studio 2012 can compile binaries compatible with Windows XP SP3.

You need to install the Platform Toolset v110_xp and select it in the general configuration properties of your project.

If "safe" means that it works the answere is yes. We have 12.000 installations of our software compiled with Visual Studio 2012 (and recently Visual Studio 2013) perfectly working on Windows XP SP3.

The only big problem is run time debugging: you can't install Visual Studio 2012 on Windows XP so it could be a problem to find bugs that accidentally happens only on Windows XP.

Comment: But does it support (or "compatible") with earlier XP releases?

Comment: Microsoft says Windows XP SP3. You can check here [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661358/en-us)